# How to use jquery variables inside function calls in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a textarea something like this:

```
<textarea id="textreview" name="textreview"></textarea>
```

On the click of a button, I need this pass this information to a controller action defined inside the controller.

```
<button onclick="sendReview()"></button>
```

The jquery sendReview() function looks like this:

```
<script>
    function sendReview() {
        var textreview = $('#textreview').val();
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ControllerAction", "ControllerName", new { review = textreview })'
    }
</script>
```

However, unfortunately I get an error:

> The name textreview does not exist in the current content

How can I send the parameter to the controller action?

Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Comment: You can't. I'd suggest you research the difference between client side and server side code. To do what you require you would need to use AJAX.

Comment: `window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ControllerAction", "ControllerName")' + '?review=' + textreview;` But you should be using form with `FormMethod.Get`

Comment: You can use it like `window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ControllerAction", "ControllerName")' + '?review=' + textreview`. However better option should be to Post form

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. After so much struggle and SOing, I am considering shifting over to Ajax finally.